# Translation of the "Go" button in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What is the correct translation of the "Go" button in German?

On Stackoverflow there's [a picture of that button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470439/replace-go-button-on-soft-keyboard-with-next-in-phonegap).

My question is general. In English it is possible to write go in different circumstances like when I perform an action or when I am at the end of a wizard. 
Does such a word exist in German?

Comment: Is that a generic button or is it app-specific? If generic, it would be "enter" or (rarely) "los"

Comment: There is also the "[Microsoft terminology database](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/de-de/Search.aspx?sString=go&langID=de-de)" which includes translations of "Go" like "OK", "Los" or "Start".

Comment: @UweKeim Great Link. You should make that an answer :) On the German soft keyboard in front of me its either `Weiter` (next) or `Los` (go) depending on the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple translation for “go!” (that is independent of the individual action) is „los!“ as in

> auf die Plätze, fertig, **los!**
>   (on your marks, get set, **go!**)

Comment: "Los!" is also rather short, so it might just fit into a "Go!" button without the need to resize it.

Comment: "Start" habe ich häufiger gesehen, aber "Los" trifft es auch sehr gut.

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal translation of *go*.

*Los* is quite informal, so I’d be hesitant to use it in most contexts. Might be okay when entering a url.

If possible, use a description of the action that will be triggered. For example *Suchen*, *Verarbeitung starten* or *Registrierung abschließen*.

For the last step of a wizard, Microsoft uses *Fertigstellen*, for intermediate steps they use *Weiter/Zurück*.

For the on-screen keyboard from your example, you could use *OK* or an arrow pointing to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd translate

> Go

to

> Öffnen

or

> Suchen

in German (I don't really understand the function of this specific Go Button).

Comment: I clarified the question

Comment: Well there isn't a general word in German (at least not to my knowledge). You can see that yourself by installing apps which use some sort of "Go"-Button and then just switch the language of your keyboard to German and see what happens.